# Struts2 tags in divs appear empty

Tags: html, css, struts2, struts

I have a s:checkbox inside a html div. When the code is run, the checkbox is outside (both) the div and the divs seem to be empty and nonexistant. Why is this occuring and how can I fix it? When I place random text inside either div, the div contains it. I set the background color to red so I can detect the div.

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <s:checkbox name="chBx" id"chBx" fieldValue="false" value="true" label="Check 
            This" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It has something to do with Struts tags adding table tags to its html. Its not a complete answer but it's similar to this situation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503610/how-can-i-position-multiple-struts-textfields-into-4-seperate-blocks-in-one-form

Comment: It's exactly that. Stop using the default XHTML theme (if you never want Struts2 to generate additional HTML for you) by setting SIMPLE theme globally in struts.xml, or (if you are fine with HTML generated everywhere EXCEPT that in some points) use SIMPLE theme on single tags / forms by specifying them inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503610/how-can-i-position-multiple-struts-textfields-into-4-seperate-blocks-in-one-form) (that you should consider upvoting too), Struts2 generates (or not) [a certain kind of HTML when rendering Struts Tags](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/struts-2-themes.html), basing [on the Theme](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html) you have chosen.

The default one is `xhtml`, that will generate *a lot* of stuff for you. It may be handy, but also annoying, according to how you work. Personally I prefer to generate the HTML by myself, and then I use the theme that won't generate almost any HTML: the `simple` Theme.

Note that when working on big projects or with multiple projects with the same, particular needs, you can also write your own custom theme (for example for generating security tokens automatically).

You can use a theme globally (in struts.xml)

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

or locally to a single tag / form:

```
<s:checkbox name="chBx" id"chBx" fieldValue="false" 
           theme="simple"
           value="true" label="Check This" />
```

In this case, you may need to write the `<label>` object by yourself.