# Struts2 action result not directing to model from which the action was called

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, struts2

I am using a bootstrap model to present a signup form. I am doing the validation in the validate method of my action class. I have set my struts.xml as follows

```
<action name="signUp" class = "xyz.SignUpActionClass" method ="execute">
    <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/sign-up.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Now in case of validation failure I go back to index.jsp but the model containing the form is not opened automatically. And the `addFieldError()`
method does not print the error message next to the form element having invalid input.

How is it possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28558436/1654265

Comment: It's unclear what do you want to do. For better help, sooner post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).