# show struts2 action error messages on to Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, struts2, modal-dialog

Now I have a sign up modal #modal_A: when user click a link, popover the modal_A dialog, then user can submit his/her infor, but when the username is invalid, some error message should shown on the modal based on the struts2.

Here is the signup form on jsp page:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm login-position" role="document">
    <div class="modal-cell">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="login-modal">
            <div class="omb_login">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-11 login-left">  
                        <s:form class="omb_loginForm" name="register" theme="simple" action="RegisterAction" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size: 15px;"></i></span>
                                <s:textfield type="text" class="form-control line-height" name="username" id="username_register" placeholder="User name"/>
                            </div>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>

                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="font-size: 9px;"></i></span>
                                <s:textfield type="text" class="form-control line-height" name="email" id="email_register" placeholder="Email"/>
                            </div>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>

                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone-square" style="font-size: 13px;"></i></span>
                                <s:textfield type="text" class="form-control line-height" name="telephone" id="telephone_register" placeholder="Telephone"/>
                            </div>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>

                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock" style="font-size: 18px;"></i></span>
                                <s:textfield  type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password_register" placeholder="Password"/>
                            </div>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                            <s:submit id="hide" class="btn btn-lg login-btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" key="register.register"/>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </s:form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the struts action:

```
<action name="RegisterAction" class="RegisterAction">
       <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>    
       <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>   
</action>
```

Here is the validators:

```
<validators>
<field name="username">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message>test!!!!!!!!!!</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
</validators>
```

Now when the username is null, I expect it can show the message on the modal.

But the problem is that: when the username is null, **it directly jump to the index.jsp page but without the modal shown.** So how to solve it?

Comment: You are opening the modal the first time, right ? Then you need to handle the input/error cases and reopen the modal on page load, in a nutshell. Please show more details, I can't see any modal here and this is the max we can do with the code provided. Also read this that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28558436/1654265

Comment: @zhanzhan I am using bootstrap modal..in order show validation errors i am using type=json in struts.xml and instead of using s:form submitting form through jquery(Passing the field values through AJAX)...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts.xml Adding result type...

```
     <result-types>
                    <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
            </result-types>
```

Struts Action

```
        <action name="RegisterAction" class="RegisterAction">
        <result name="INPUT">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="ERROR" type="json">/index.jsp</result>
        <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
        <param name="includeProperties">actionErrors\[\d+\], fieldErrors\..+$, actionMessages\[\d+\]</param>
        <result name="success" type="json">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

In Jsp page

```
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size: 15px;"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control line-height" name="username" id="username_register" placeholder="User name"/>
<input type="button"  id="username_submit" />
</div>
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#username_submit").click(function(){
           var username=$("#username_register").val();
       $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url:'RegisterAction?username='+encodeURIComponent(username),
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data){
            if(data.fieldErrors && !isEmpty(data.fieldErrors)){
           $.each(data.fieldErrors,function(index,value){ //indexfieldname,valuefiled?
          $("#username_register").before('<span>'+value[0]+'</span>');
            });
           return;
           } 



           },
                   error: function() 
                   {

                   }
        });
        return false;
       });});


function isEmpty(obj){//(Object obj = {}isEmpty=true)
    for(var p in obj){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

NOTE:Add struts2json plugin Jar..and In alert u will be having struts2 validation errors...hope this will help u :)

Comment: @Zhan did you try this...??

Comment: Sorry, i have a meal with my friends just now. Now I'm trying this.

Comment: cool! now when the submit button is submitted, it will be stay on the modal. But another problem occurs: There is no any error message shown on the modal.  I inspect the webpage, I find there is a error: `GET http://localhost:8080/gotwiss/RegisterAction?username=testname 404 (Not Found)`. can you tell me why? pls

Comment: OK! I didn't find any error things in the js code. I want the validator message shown on the modal, but it doesn't work. do you want to see the whole code(js, xml and validator)?

Comment: You r getting error in alert right ?? show me your js

Comment: I want to show the error message based on the validation xml file as post above, that is to say, the "user name is null" message doesn't rely on the js function isEmpty(). the js code is still yours. Btw, we have decide another approach for this problem.

Comment: @ZhanzhanCheng On StackOverflow you should post a new question as (guess what) a new question, not in comments to (or even worst, by editing) the original, already answered question. This is a new problem, so please open a new question