# Struts2 Bootstrap Plugin 2.5.0 - list group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, plugins, struts2, struts2-bootstrap-plugin

I am a beginner using *Struts2 Bootstrap Plugin 2.5.0*, on Eclipse Neon.
I use dependency maven *Maven Struts2 Bootstrap Plugin*.
I've successfully created a login page calling a action, and then return to another page (menu page).

My question is:

I would like to use a **dropdown-menu** and  **list-group**;

Since in the Struts2 Bootstrap Plugin Showcase the **list-group** does not exist, should I need to include bootstrap-3.3.7 in my project ?

Answer (score 1):

Struts2 plugins (jQuery plugin, Bootstrap plugin, etc...) have the purpose of helping you integrating different technologies in a transparent way, without forcing you to immediately learn those technologies.

You write a simple Struts tag and, thanks to a special theme (the `bootstrap` theme, in this case), 
[the HTML generated will be Bootstrap-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28558436/1654265).

In order to do this, **the plugin has *already* in it the latest version of Bootstrap** ([the 3.3.7, as you can see on GitHub](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-bootstrap/tree/master/struts2-bootstrap-plugin)), so, to answer your question

> Since in the Struts2 Bootstrap Plugin Showcase the list-group does not
>   exist, should I need to include bootstrap-3.3.7 in my project ?

If the tag you want has not been implemented, you can still manually write its raw (bootstrap-compliant) HTML, exploiting the Bootstrap library bundled with the plugin.

You have no need to include that library again, it is already in your project.

Note: the latest version of the plugin is 2.5.1.

Comment: Thank you Andrea. If I want  to customize the Bootstrap component on changing font, border, colours, etc...I must include in my project the css/js files of the  plugin on GitHub?

Comment: Sounds like another question to me. And you still haven't upvoted nor accepted this one... ;)