# How can I use Bootstrap with struts 2?

Tags: struts2

I am beginner of struts2 and bootstarp. I can not use bootstrap with my struts2 form . I am using the following Jar:

```
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
common-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
freemaker-2.3.19.jar
javaassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
mysql-connector.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
struct2-core-2.3.14.2.jar
xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
asm-tree-3.3.jar
```

my jsp page is below:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<s:form action="loginprocess" cssClass="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
  <s:textfield name="username"  ></s:textfield>
   </div>
 </div>



 <div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">  
<s:password name="userpass"   ></s:password>
 </div>
 </div>


 <s:submit value="login"></s:submit>

<div class="form-group"> 
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </s:form>

Not registered yet ,Please Sign Up
<a href ="index.jsp">Sign Up</a>


</body>
</html>
```

but it gives a horrible output where all elements are broken. Output is below:

[output of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWjg6.png)

which extra jar files I need to add to my project? or what more things is require to create form using struts2 and bootstrap? Please help.

Comment: Please help me as early as possible

Comment: https://struts.apache.org/docs/themes-and-templates.html.

Comment: https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-bootstrap.

Comment: Also related, if using the plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28558436/1654265

Answer (score 1):

Add `theme="simple"` to all struts elements.
Like :-

```
<s:form action="loginprocess" cssClass="form-horizontal" theme="simple">
```